# How to render packed isometric tilesheet

Tags: rendering

For those who know Adobe Flash / Animate, when you export an animation, it can automatically create a packed tilesheet with a xml coordinates file such as

[image]

`frames.xml`

```
<frames>
    <frame x="0" y="0" w="256" h="512">
    <frame x="256" y="0" w="256" h="512">
    ....
```

How can I export a packed isometric spritesheet such as the one below in blender?

[image]

Comment: Why not using a sprite sheet packer with Blender rendered image sequence?

Comment: @HikariTW If I could do that with blender, it would streamline and speed up my workflow. Updating any change would be as simple as 1 click export instead of having to recreate the spritesheet everytime . And adobe does it, so why not blender.

Comment: Did you search any add-on do the same thing? There is a [PyTexturePacker](https://github.com/wo1fsea/PyTexturePacker) module which could handle your problem. But it need to implemented to Blender add-on with exporter(?).